# Where to start exploring/evaluating a ASP.Net Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I received the below ASP.Net project. I need to understand the working of this webserver from its code. Where should I start exploring this project from I am a newbie in ASP.Net and C#. Which file among the below will contain the server listening command?

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omebT.png)

Comment: If you are asking this question, then the real problem is that you have no idea how ASP.NET works, which means you need to go and learn some basics first.

Comment: Agreed! I was looking at ASP.Net Project structures, but the file extensions varied a lot.

Comment: So if you agree, why are you asking questions here rather than spending time learning? :)

Comment: Tackling a big codebase while learning is tough. Anyways I have to learn this to make changes for my product so not learning is not an option. Just having some insights about the project structure and its important files will be helpful. Thank You.

Comment: Bad news is that it's written by chinese devs with chinese comments throughout the code. Please some insights would be helpful

Comment: I already gave you the best insight you will get - go learn the basics of how ASP.NET projects work and this question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Ok can you tell the ASP.Net version of this code or the release year which I should be learning for this project?

Comment: It looks like WebForms, pretty old stuff.

Comment: The point that DavidG is being coy about is this: the direct answer to the question in your final sentence is "none of them". IIS, a component of Windows Server, does the port listening, and based on the HTTP headers, decides where to send the request. An HttpModule which is also part of IIS will then (most likely) start processing Default.ASPX, using the ASPX file to scaffold the HTML and the .associated cs file to execute code. The rest of the .CS files are probably called by the Default.ASPX.cs file. 

If an HTTP request comes in for /something/else.aspx then IIS will return 404.

Answer (score 0):

.cs files are the "C-Sharp" code behind files.  The ones in the AppCode folder are likely relevant to the project.  You should also investigate the "Default.aspx" and associated "Default.aspx.cs" file.  This is the default webpage and code-behind file.  This does appear to be webforms at first glance.  Also, your "web.config" file will likely have server/application configuration information in it.  The ".sln" file is your solution file. 
 That is essentially the File that you can use to open in visual studio, and it should pull in the necessary configs/files to build the project.  Open the files up and start exploring.